# high latency on elasticsearch requests

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, time, latency

I am using the Transport Client to index data. Here's a small test program:

```
@Test
public void LatencyTest() throws Exception {
    // warmup
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        client.prepareGet("ts_head", "doc", "latency_test_id").get();
    }

    List<Long> times = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        final long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        final IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("ts_head", "doc", "latency_test_id").setSource("{}", XContentType.JSON).get();
        final long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        times.add(t2 - t1);
    }
    final double average = times.stream().mapToLong(v -> v).average().getAsDouble();
    System.out.println("Average time: " + (average / 1_000_000f) + "ms");
}
```

the output is: `Average time: 79.3905588ms`, which seems awfully slow. It accesses a cluster consisting of 2 nodes (both master) over a local network with a gigabit connection. The network itself doesn't seem to have high latency:

```
$ ping -U 172.***
PING 172.*** (172.***) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.***: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.324 ms
64 bytes from 172.***: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.280 ms
64 bytes from 172.***: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.348 ms
64 bytes from 172.***: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=0.306 ms
```

Indexing via HTTP is pretty slow as well:

```
$ curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -X POST -s "http://172.***:9200/ts_head/doc/latency_test_id" --data '{}'
{"_index":"ts_head","_type":"doc","_id":"latency_test_id","_version":211,"result":"updated","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":2,"failed":0},"created":false}    time_namelookup:  0,001381
       time_connect:  0,135607
    time_appconnect:  0,000000
   time_pretransfer:  0,136056
      time_redirect:  0,000000
 time_starttransfer:  0,283840
                    ----------
         time_total:  0,284044
```

Now my question is: What am I doing wrong? Elasticsearch must surely be capable of indexing faster, right?

For testing, I also read data, and it reported `"took": 1`, but still too consistently over 100ms to respond via curl.